# How do I connect a Python program in Visual Studio Code to MySQL Workbench 8.0?

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code, connection, mysql-workbench

I am creating a program that uses VS Code and MySQL Workbench 8.0 together. I am stuck and do not know how to connect the two software together

I also have to be able to upload records into a table that is stored in MySQL Workbench from the Python program that uses variables.

Please tell me if their are any details missing.
Thank you.

For connection:

I have researched on Google and have been unable to find an answer. I have found that I have to install certain packages and use the connect method. However, I do not know the parameters of the connect function.

For uploading data into table:

I have found that I have to create a cursor to somehow upload the data to the table, but am unsusre of the full details.

Comment: how can your program **use** VSC, you use VSC to create the program (text file), the stuff is not stored in MySQL Workbench, MySQL Workbench is a viewer of the MySQL database just as your program is a viewer of the MySQL database, The Python program does **not** run in VSC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many packages in python that can connect to the mysql database, here we take `pymysql` as an example.

- Install `pymysql`

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

[image]

*I have already installed, so the prompt package already exists.*

- Sample code, query and insert data

```
import pymysql

con = pymysql.Connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=3306,
    user='root',
    password='123456',
    db='test',
    charset='utf8'
)

cur = con.cursor()

sql1 = 'select * from student'
cur.execute(sql1)
data = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
con.close()

for i in data:
    print(str(i))
```

[image]

Add an insert data statement, and re-query after inserting data.

```
import pymysql

con = pymysql.Connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=3306,
    user='root',
    password='123456',
    db='test',
    charset='utf8'
)

cur = con.cursor()


sql2 = 'insert into student values("002","jerry","W");'
cur.execute(sql2)

sql1 = 'select * from student'
cur.execute(sql1)

data = cur.fetchall()
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()

for i in data:
    print(str(i))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer @JialeDu. Sorry, I still have one more question. Where do I install the PyMySQL package. Do I write the command in VSCode or in my Command prompt. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you. Both the vscode integrated terminal and the external cmd window can install the pymysql package. The key is to ensure that it is installed in the correct environment and select the correct interpreter in vscode. The picture in my answer is using the pip command under the vscode integrated terminal, and is installing in a virtual environment.

Comment: I tried the code but I still got another error. I have researched the error but have been unable to find its relevance to connecting Python programs to MYSQL Workbench 8.0. 

If you have the answer please post it on its question page - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74358734/python-error-unpack-requires-a-buffer-of-4-bytes-when-using-pymysql