# Python error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes, when using PyMySQL,

Tags: python, mysql, error-handling, pymysql

I am connecting a Python program in Visual Studio Code to a SQL databse stored in MySQL Workbench 8.0. I am using the PyMySQL connector to do this. However, I am running into an error with code that I have used from another question that I have posted. Here is the link and the code:

[How do I connect a Python program in Visual Studio Code to MySQL Workbench 8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74250505/how-do-i-connect-a-python-program-in-visual-studio-code-to-mysql-workbench-8-0/74259790#74259790)

```
pip install PyMySQL


import pymysql

con = pymysql.Connect(
    host='localhost',
    port=3306,
    user='root',
    password='123456',
    db='test',
    charset='utf8'
)

cur = con.cursor()

sql1 = 'select * from student'
cur.execute(sql1)
data = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
con.close()

for i in data:
    print(str(i))
```

[image: code screenshot]

Here is a screenshot with my code and the error that I received.

I tried the code that I recieved from my previous question, but it resulted in an another error. I am pretty sure I have copied the code correctly and the database details. I have researched the error but have been unable to find its relevance to connecting Python programs to MYSQL Workbench 8.0 with PyMySQL.

Comment: Why not show your own code? The code in the picture is not the same as the code you pasted as text. And `pip install pymysql` is a command, it's not a code.

Comment: Is your database name and table name the same? Why are there no parentheses after your `fetchall` method? Is this what you mean by copying the code correctly?

Comment: Has your mysql modified the port number? Why is the port number `33060` in the code in the picture?

Comment: @JialeDu watched a video on setting up the connection in MySQL Workbench and it recommended using the port 33060 because it has a stronger connection. This is the video that it said it in.

Comment: Otherwise thank you for pointing out the typos. I will fix them now and see whether the program runs smoothly.

Comment: But did you modify the port while installing? Does changing the port number in the code to 3306 remove the error?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, obviously you didn't copy the code in the answer correctly.**

Your code has the following errors (only from the picture, I don't know what your complete code looks like)

- The port number is `3306`. NOT `33060`. Of course, if you make changes when you install the database, you need to change it to the port number you use.
- The `fetchall` method in `data = cur.fetchall` does parentheses. It shoud be `data = cur.fetchall()`.

**At the moment it seems that the error in the picture is due to the port number.**

Modifying to the correct port number will remove this error.

Comment: What's your mistake? What does your code look like now? What error are you getting?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I put this connection into my main program and have had some errors in that. I have posted that in another question. It would be helpful if you could answer that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74372581/need-some-debugging-in-my-program-filling-up-sql-tables-with-data-retrieved-fro

Comment: What about this question? What you're doing is confusing.