# Need some debugging in my program: filling up SQL tables with data retrieved from a Python program

Tags: python, mysql, debugging

I am filling up SQL tables with data that I have retrieved from a Python program. I am using Visual Studio Code for the Python program and MySQL Workbench 8.0 for SQL. There are some errors in it that I cannot resolve.

Here is my code:

```
from gettext import install                                       #Importing PyMySQL extension
import pymysql

con = pymysql.Connect(                                            #Establishing connection
    host = 'localhost',                                                 #
    port = 3306,                                                        #
    user = 'root',                                                      #
    password = 'Musa2014',                                              #
    db = 'referees',                                                    #
    charset = 'utf8'                                                    #
)

Ref_Info = input("Enter referee details: ")                       #First input statement

Ref_First_Name, Ref_Last_Name, Ref_Level = Ref_Info.split()       #Establishing individual variables

Ref_Info_Table = []

RefID = 1                                                         #Setting the value of the RefID

cur = con.cursor()                                                #Setting up cursor

while Ref_Info != 'Stop':                                         #Creating loop to get referee information 
    
    Ref_Info_Table.append(Ref_Info.split())                       #Updating Ref_Info_Table with new referee data
    print(Ref_Info_Table)                                         #Checking for bugs        
    print(Ref_Info.split())                                             #
    print(RefID, Ref_Info)                                              #
    print('Referee ID:', RefID)                                         #
    print('Referee First Name:', Ref_First_Name)                        #
    print('Referee Last Name:', Ref_Last_Name)                          #
    print('Referee Level:', Ref_Level)                                  #
    RefID = RefID + 1                                             #Increasing the value of RefId
    Ref_First_Name, Ref_Last_Name, Ref_Level = Ref_Info.split() 
    sql_query1 = 'INSERT INTO ref_info VALUES(RefID, Ref_First_Name, Ref_Last_Name, Ref_Level)'
    sql_query2 = 'SELECT * FROM ref_info'
    cur.execute(sql_query1)
    cur.execute(sql_query2)
    Ref_Info = input("Enter referee details: ")                   #Establishing recurring input again

sql_query3 = 'SELECT * FROM ref_info'
cur.execute(sql_query3)
data = cur.fetchall()
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Here is the output in the terminal with the errors.

> Windows PowerShell
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

> Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

> PS C:\Users\mahd_.vscode\Code Folders\Testing> & C:/Users/mahd_/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/mahd_/.vscode/Code Folders/Testing/connection.py"
>
> PS C:\Users\mahd_.vscode\Code Folders\Testing> & C:/Users/mahd_/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/mahd_/.vscode/Code Folders/Testing/connection.py"
>
> PS C:\Users\mahd_.vscode\Code Folders\Testing> & C:/Users/mahd_/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/mahd_/.vscode/Code Folders/Testing/connection.py"
>
> PS C:\Users\mahd_.vscode\Code Folders\Testing> & C:/Users/mahd_/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/mahd_/.vscode/Code Folders/Testing/connection.py"

```
Enter referee details: Josh Allen 2
[['Zac', 'Constable', '3'], ['Josh', 'Allen', '2']]
['Josh', 'Allen', '2']
2 Josh Allen 2
Referee ID: 2
Referee First Name: Zac
Referee Last Name: Constable
Referee Level: 3
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\mahd_.vscode\Code Folders\Testing\connection.py", line 37, in 
> cur.execute(sql_query1)
>
> File "C:\Users\mahd_\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 148, in execute
> result = self.*query(query)
>
> File "C:\Users\mahd*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 310, in *query
> conn.query(q)
>
> File "C:\Users\mahd*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 548, in query
> self.*affected_rows = self.*read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
>
> File "C:\Users\mahd*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 775, in *read_query_result
> result.read()
>
> File "C:\Users\mahd*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 1156, in read
> first_packet = self.connection.*read_packet()
>
> File "C:\Users\mahd*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 725, in *read_packet
> packet.raise_for_error()
>
> File "C:\Users\mahd*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pymysql\protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
> err.raise_mysql_exception(self.*data)
>
> File "C:\Users\mahd*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
> raise errorclass(errno, errval)
>
> pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'ref_info.PRIMARY'")
>
> PS C:\Users\mahd*.vscode\Code Folders\Testing>

Comment: I am getting an error in line 38 of my program: cur.execute(sql_query1).  Exception has occurred: IntegrityError
(1062, "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'ref_info.PRIMARY'")
  File "C:\Users\mahd_\.vscode\Code Folders\Testing\connection.py", line 38, in <module>
    cur.execute(sql_query1)

Comment: Provide the result of a `SHOW CREATE TABLE ref_info` and `SHOW INDEXES FROM ref_info`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is nothing int the table ref_info. It is empty.

Comment: How do I edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

`"Duplicate entry '0' for key 'ref_info.PRIMARY'"` means that you try to insert a record in the `ref_info` table that already exists.
A primary key is unique.