# How can I create a mysql database on vscode?

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code, flask

I'm trying to follow the flask app tutorial by traversy media. I am now in part 2 where you use mysql. Up until now, ive done everything on vscode (created venv, run flaskapp, etc) but now how do i go about using mysql on the terminal. I downloaded the extension and got this error: ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306. So do i have to set it up in cmd line and integrate it?

Here is the link to the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=addnlzdSQs4&list=PLillGF-RfqbbbPz6GSEM9hLQObuQjNoj_&index=3

and here is a link to what might help. but how do i go from this to vscode.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyW83fDBt5A

Comment: You will have to install and start the MySQL server.

Comment: If you want to connect to mysql in vscode using python, check out the answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74250505/how-do-i-connect-a-python-program-in-visual-studio-code-to-mysql-workbench-8-0/74259790#74259790